# org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding$BindingTableModel cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jsr296, beans-binding

I tried to group JTable header and for that I want to get the DefaultTableModel of current JTable. But when I tried to retrieve the table model like this:

```
DefaultTableModel dm=(DefaultTableModel) tblTet.getModel();
```

It shows the following exception:

> org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding$BindingTableModel cannot be
>   cast to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel

Because I am using JTableBeansBinding.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem (for retrieving DefaultTableModel)?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [JavaDoc for BindingTableModel](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/java/dev/beansbinding/beansbinding/1.2.1/beansbinding-1.2.1.jar!/org/jdesktop/swingbinding/JTableBinding%24BindingTableModel.class?classDetails=ok), the class doesn't extend DefaultTableModel.  Rather, it implements TableModel interface.  This means that you cannot cast to DefaultTableModel, only to TableModel:

```
TableModel dm=(TableModel) tblTet.getModel();
```

Answer (score -3):

you have to create your table like this :

```
    String[] columnNames = {"Row",
            "Category",
            "From Date",
            "From Time",
            "To Date",
            "To Time",
            "Description",
            "Doc"};
    Object[][] data = {};//Table Rows

   table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames));
```

instead of:

```
   table=new JTable(data,columnNames);
```

then you can cast your table model to defaultTableModel.

Comment: normally, yes. But the OP is using (Better)BeansBinding and has no control about the type of the internally assigned TableModel