# How to add row to a jtable that is bound to database in jframe form

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to add new row on the JTable when it saves the information to the database, it works for adding row to database. However, it doesn't work when I am trying to add row to the JTable.

```
DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
jTable1.setModel(table);
table.addRow(new Object[]{TChampion.getText(),score,kill,death,asisst});
```

But, I got an error( I used try and catch):

> org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding$BindingTableModel cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel

Comment: You should include a [MCVE] so people can try to reproduce your problem. I do not see any problem with the short snippet you posted.

Comment: this basically all I have in the code

Comment: Read this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10132017/243373. The take away: cast to `TableModel` instead of `DefaultTableModel`.